# What is MSSQL exception code for "SHUTDOWN is in progress. Login failed for user ''XXXX''. Only administrators may connect at this time."

Tags: sql-server, exception, server

I want to know the SQL Exception error code for the above exception. It occurs when there is an unexpected sql cluster service shutdown, and an application tries to access the server.

Comment: The message indicate us server resources are not ready on requested time for some reasons like Restarting the virtual machine or etc ... .

Answer (score 10):

These are two separate messages: "SHUTDOWN is in progress" (code 6005) and "Login failed for user '%.*ls'. Only administrators may connect at this time.%.*ls" (code 18451). You can determine this by querying `sys.messages`:

```
select * from sys.messages 
where [text] like '%only administrators%' or [text] like 'SHUTDOWN is in progress%'
and language_id = 1033
```

Because "SHUTDOWN is in progress" has [severity 10](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms164086), it's merely informational and will not result in an exception. "Login failed" will, however (and the "SHUTDOWN" message will be incorporated into it).

Note that if your server has already shut down, or is in the process of shutting down and its network name is no longer accessible, you can get other errors during the connection attempt that aren't generated by the server. Looking for this error is not a reliable way of detecting a shutdown condition, and you probably shouldn't have special-case logic for it.

Answer (score 0):

ERROR 6005 - Shutdown is in progress

List of errors in this group: http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-6001-7000.aspx

Likely related to SQL Server cluster