# SQL Shutdown In Progress -- what is the cause?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I got the following message while querying a database to pull data to retrain a model. I do not have sysadmin access or anything like that, I am merely a user of a larger database shared by our whole organization. I'm trying to understand what this message means; is our SQL server doing a shutdown or have I potentially done something to cause this? All I have done before seeing this error message is import libraries and run the query.

```
('42000', '[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]SHUTDOWN is in progress. (6005) (SQLExecDirectW)')
unable to rollback
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is MSSQL exception code for "SHUTDOWN is in progress. Login failed for user ''XXXX''. Only administrators may connect at this time."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27400749/what-is-mssql-exception-code-for-shutdown-is-in-progress-login-failed-for-user)

Comment: @Larnu so probably not my fault then and something else is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are set up correctly, you would never be able to shut down a SQL Server instance as a user.

Based on what you've said, importing libraries would not cause a SQL Server shutdown.  This would be done purposely by an administrator of the database.

I would suggest informing your IT team.  Hopefully this was for some planned maintenance.